# Get different class types by `var` from inherited objects

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I need to get different class types by `var` from inherited objects. and I need these objects to be not generic. something like this

```
import Foundation

protocol MyClassProtocol {
    associatedtype MyClass: Any
    var myClass: MyClass.Type { get }
}

extension MyClassProtocol {
    var myClass: MyClass.Type {
        get { Self.MyClass.self }
    }
}

class A: MyClassProtocol {
    typealias MyClass = String
}

class B: A {
    typealias MyClass = Int64
}

let a = A().myClass     // String.Type
let a1 = A.MyClass.self // String.Type
let b = B().myClass     // String.Type
let b1 = B.MyClass.self // Int64.Type

let list: [A] = [A(),B()]

// any way, how i get from this list different classes?
let la = list[0].myClass                 // String.Type
let la1 = type(of: list[0]).MyClass.self // String.Type
let lb = list[1].myClass                 // String.Type
let lb1 = type(of: list[1]).MyClass.self // String.Type
```

how I can resolve it? I cant use generic because I have `array: [A]`

Comment: You are getting `String.Type` because `list[1]` is of type `A` since `list` is of type `[A]`. If you casted it as `B` you would get `Int64.Type` like `type(of: list[1] as! B).MyClass.self`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this kind of functionality, you will have store the class type as an instance variable and utilize class types that conform to `AnyClass` aka `AnyObject.Type` like below.

There is no practical reason to do this, and it is highly discouraged, but if you want to call something like `classB.staticMethod()` this is how you would do it.

```swift
class MyCustomClass: NSObject {
    @objc
    static func myStaticMethod() { print("why the heck do i need this?") }
}

protocol MyClassProtocol {
    var myClass: AnyClass { get }
}

class A: MyClassProtocol {
    var myClass: AnyClass { return NSString.self }
}

class B: A {
    override var myClass: AnyClass { return MyCustomClass.self }
}

var list: [MyClassProtocol] = [A(), B()]
let classA: AnyClass = list[0].myClass.self // NSString
let classB: AnyClass = list[1].myClass.self // MyCustomClass

if classB.responds(to: #selector(MyCustomClass.myStaticMethod)) {
    classB.performSelector(inBackground: #selector(MyCustomClass.myStaticMethod), 
                           with: nil)
}
```

Comment: but how do you do anything with `anyClass`? example - list [1] .myClass.self.myStaticVar (doesn't work)